# Microsoft StreamBufferEngine support two sources to one sink?

Tags: directshow

Is it possible to have a single Stream Buffer Sink feed two Stream Buffer Source's?  What I would like to do is have three graphs. The first is my capture graph, feeding into a Stream Buffer Sink. The second is a preview graph using a Stream Buffer Source. I then want an independent graph with a sample grabber for getting images out also tied to the sink, but that I can seek indepently of the video preview.

Is this possible?  My initial testing has not been working well.

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0):

I'm think you might use something like the [GMFBridge](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/gmfbridge/index.htm#20100617). This is an API that makes it possible to transfer data from one graph, to another. You could for instance create a graph looking like this:

[image: GMFBridge example graph]

With this setup, you can start and stop the preview graph and samplegrabber graph as you'd like.

-Svein

Comment: That isn't quite what I am looking for. I want the features of the Stream Buffer Engine where I can scrub through the video while recording and also where it uses a circular buffer rather than a single file.

Comment: Have you tride a similar setup to the one decribed above? Instead of having one stream buffer sink feeding two stream buffer sources, splitting the video with something similar to the infinite pin tee filter, then having one sink for each source?

Comment: I haven't tried this yet. This has become lower priority at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  This is possible.  For example, our application uses a service to record via the SBE sink filter which the UI then displays using the SBE source filter.   Another service provides a network stream of the same data recorded via the SBE Sink filter using another instance of the SBE Source filter.